# Append Multi Dimensional Tuples in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, datetime, tuples

I hope you all are fine.

I got two panda series that were taken from an dependent datetime; both of them with the same length, i.e.:

```py
    print(A)
    2020-04-24 00:00:00-05:00    559
    2020-04-25 00:00:00-05:00    554
    2020-04-26 00:00:00-05:00    489
    2020-04-27 00:00:00-05:00    661
    2020-04-28 00:00:00-05:00    320
    2020-04-29 00:00:00-05:00    524

    print(B)
    2020-04-24 00:00:00-05:00    39
    2020-04-25 00:00:00-05:00    39
    2020-04-26 00:00:00-05:00    40
    2020-04-27 00:00:00-05:00    49
    2020-04-28 00:00:00-05:00    28
    2020-04-29 00:00:00-05:00    45
    2020-04-30 00:00:00-05:00    11
```

I need to create an array of tuples in the form:

```py
    array_of_tuples = [(559, 39),
                       (554, 39),
                       (489, 40),
                       (661, 49),
                       (320, 45),
                       (524, 11)]
```

Any idea of how can I do that?

Comment: `list(zip(s1.values, s2.values))`

Comment: Yes, Yatu. Thanks a lot for taking your time and help me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've shown is a *list* of tuples. You can just use `zip` for this:

```
In [11]: s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['a','b','c'])

In [12]: s2 = pd.Series([42, 88, 99], index=['a','b','c'])

In [13]: s1
Out[13]:
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64

In [14]: s2
Out[14]:
a    42
b    88
c    99
dtype: int64

In [15]: list(zip(s1, s2))
Out[15]: [(1, 42), (2, 88), (3, 99)]
```

Comment: Perfect, Juanpa. Thanks for taking your time and give me such an explanation. It is very nice! :)